# How do I dynamically allocated/grow an array of strings in C++?

Tags: c++, dynamic-arrays

Looking around I have found what I thought were to be solutions to my problem. Right now I am trying to read from a txt file.

snippet from the file:

11111,"random phrase"

11123,"this is nonsense"

13212,"silly words"

```
int arraylen = 2;
string line, field;
string* num = new string[arraylen];
string* phrase = new string[arraylen];


ifstream myfile;
myfile.open("data.txt");




int i = 0, test = 0;


while(!myfile.eof())
{
    getline(myfile,line);
    stringstream ss(line);
    while(getline(ss,field,','))
    {
        if(test == 0)
        {
            num[i] = field;
            cout << "rum: " << num[i] << endl;
            test = 1;

        }
        else
        {
            phrase[i] = field;
            cout << "phrase: " << phrase[i] << endl;
            test = 0;               
        }

        if(i == (arraylen-1))
        {
            arraylen = arraylen + 1;
            string* temp = new string[arraylen];
            copy(num, num + 2, temp);
            delete [] num;
            num = temp;
            copy(phrase, phrase + 2, temp);
            delete [] phrase;
            phrase = temp;

        }


    }
    i++;
}
myfile.close();




return 0;
```

I parse the line at the commas and save the number to array num and the phrase to array phrase. I want to allow my program to read in a file whose number of lines is unknown so I will need to grow the array on the fly. Right now if I use the arrays that are commented out my program crashes.

The couts show it is reading the first two lines then crashing I assume because the array isn't long enough. Any advice on what changes need to be made so I can properly grow my arrays?

edit: I have to use arrays. I cannot use any other data structure.

Comment: Use `std::vector`.

Comment: If you insist on manual memory management (likely because of a restriction imposed by an instructor), you'll need to allocate a new array with more size, copy the contents from the previous array over, and deallocate memory for the previous array.

Comment: `std::vector<std::string>`  Problem solved.

Comment: Oh yes I have to use arrays...sadly I know vectors would trivialize this issue.

Comment: Think of it this way - if you don't know how to do it with arrays, then you aren't ready to wield the power of vectors, since vectors are essentially doing the same thing, but behind the scenes.

Comment: @RPGillespie: "If you don't know how a car engine works, then you aren't ready to drive a car, since cars use engines behind the scenes."  I strongly disagree.

Comment: @MooingDuck *If you don't know how a car engine works, then you aren't ready to drive a car, since cars use engines behind the scenes.* Exactly - and unfortunately many people are driving cars before they are ready. Using something without knowing at least generally how it works internally limits you from using it to its full potential and understanding its full implications in the bigger picture.

Comment: We're not talking about "using it to it's full potential".  I was thinking about doing basic tasks.  For which a car I don't understand is way better than a car I have to assemble myself.  I agree that to use it to the fullest you eventually have to learn the internals, but you definitely shouldn't avoid using it until you understand how it works.  If that were the case, there'd only be like 10 people on the planet allowed to use `std::cout`.

Comment: Few people know how a Wankel engine works.

Comment: @MooingDuck For someone who just wants results, then yes, I agree with you, abstractions are good. But in the context of *academia* (in which students are expected to learn and understand the inner workings), my philosophy is totally justified - nay - expected. OP lamenting that he can't use vectors but doesn't understand how to do the same thing with arrays is like a calculus student lamenting that he can't use the Power Rule to find the derivative of a polynomial when he doesn't understand differentiation to begin with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Allocate a new array. Copy the old array to the new array. Delete the old array.

```
void reallocate(std::string** old_arr, int old_size, int new_size)
{
    std::string* new_arr = new std::string[new_size];
    for (int i = 0; i < old_size; ++i)
        new_arr[i] = (*old_arr)[i];

    delete[] *old_arr;
    *old_arr = new_arr;
}
```

This is only because you can't use `std::vector` as specified in your comment. The next option is to use `std::unique_ptr` but meh.. The idea is simply, when you allocate the new array, specify the new_size as old_size * 2.. Which is usually what `std::vector` does.

Note that the code here is not exception safe, and ignores C++11 move semantics.

Comment: Wouldn't the copy() function accomplish what the for loop is doing? Or am I misunderstanding how that function works?

Comment: Yes it would: `std::copy(*old_arr, *old_arr + old_size, &new_arr[0]);`.. So would `memcpy`.

Comment: Found my error. I needed to make a new array of increased size for both old arrays instead of using just one. Side note Is it possible to grow a 2D array array[n][2] where n, the number of rows,  is unknown but the number of columns is?

Comment: @Brandon: `memcpy` of an array of `std::string` yields Undefined Behavior when using the copied objects.

Comment: Ahh I completely forgot. I thought for a second I was dealing with copying just the pointer itself. Not the string that it points to. Guess I am wrong. But `std::copy` will work so OP can use that or the for-loop.

Answer (score 2):

Just use `std::vector`.

E.g. you can add an item to the end of a `std::vector`, growing it, by using the `push_back` method.

`std::vector` is also much safer and easier than dealing directly with raw pointers and `new`.

---

If your instructor has prohibited use of standard library containers other than `std::string`, then implement a class with the relevant few features of `std::vector`. The important thing for such a class is to *take charge of copying*, known in the C++03 days as the “rule of 3”. Essentially, since it will deal with dynamic memory allocation and deallocation you will need a destructor, and therefore you need to declare (and either implement or set as `delete`) a copy constructor and a copy assignment operator.

In this class, when the current buffer size is exceeded, allocate a new buffer, copy the old contents over, deallocate the old one. A common approach to avoid O(n<sup>2</sup>) behavior is to increase the buffer size by some *factor*, and not just by a fixed number of items. Simply doubling the buffer size each time is probably good enough.

Oh yes, and it's a good idea to use a smart pointer internally.

Comment: @ryyker: OK, thanks, added a bit about such requirement.

Comment: I would love to be able to do all that unfortunately I have almost no idea how to go about using your recommendation.